# group elements in an array and sum

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following array

```
a = [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1]
```

I want to group every 3rd element and sum all of the elements within each group. So I can get a new array with a new size showing this sum

```
b = [1,0,2,0,3,0,1]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: And you've tried what and encountered what problems?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `len(a) % 3 == 0` (the length is a multiple of three)?

Comment: yes it is guaranteed

Comment: Related: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/190597).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option using `groupby` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import groupby
[sum(v for _, v in g) for _, g in groupby(enumerate(a), key = lambda x: x[0]/3)]
# [1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 1]
```

Or another way to use `zip`:

```
[sum(v) for v in zip(a[::3], a[1::3], a[2::3])]
# [1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply, most pythonicly would be the following

```
b = [sum(a[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(a), 3)]
```

where your input array is `a`.

```
>>> a = [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1]
>>> b = [sum(a[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(a), 3)]
>>> b
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can split in chunk and sum:

```
step = 3
[sum(a[i:i+step]) for i in range(0, len(a),step)]
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 1]
```

If the length is not the multiple of step, last chunk might be smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
a = [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1]
b = []

for i in range(0,len(a),3):
    b.append(sum(a[i:i+3]))
print b
```

Output:

```
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 1]
```